# Warning in @property (nonatomic,retain) UISegmentedControl *colorChooser;

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created one segmented control and  a text view in my .xib file and I have declare it in .h file as

```
@interface controlsViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *colorChooser;
    IBOutlet UITextView *setText;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UISegmentedControl *colorChooser;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITextView *setText
```

but it shows me warning on both lines of @property

Can anyone tell me why it warns me?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you don't have a [@synthesize or @dynamic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW14) in your implementation.  That would generate compiler warnings.

The position of the IBOutlet wound not generate a compiler warning as it's a marco of nothing.  It's used by xcode resource editor (or the older Interface Builder) to indicate it's a outlet property and doesn't generate any code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface controlsViewController : UIViewController {
    UISegmentedControl *colorChooser;
    UITextView *setText;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *colorChooser;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *setText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to synthesize the property in your .m file. You won't get the error then.